# How much information can humans transfer in five seconds?

Tags: humans, communication, information

Two persons can see and talk to each other a handful of seconds. How much information can they convey?

The gods host "hunger games". A huge TV-show where the universe watches a few thousands participants in a life-and death competition lasting a few months or years.
Hunger games are a well-known thing and extremely important. Participants prepare since childhood and are the best with all the support one can think of. The hunger game environment is very hard to predict. Participants may start in a sci-fi setting or gain magical abilities without advance information. They then explore the world.
The outside world has a huge information advantage. TV-shows allow them to see what participants do. Gods may share their design of how magic works. Universities research these worlds while the show goes on. Outside people are not omnipotent but they can know a lot. Unfortunately, they cannot talk to participants ... but for this one old rule. Every two weeks the gods allow participants to check up on the person most dearest to them, to see that they are alright. Of course, modern participants (and their dearest persons) abuse this rule as much as possible to gain as much of an advantage as they can. How do they do that? How much can they communicate?

Some clarifications and restrictions:

1. Participants and they informants will prepare in advance and train how to convey their message the best way possible. They can discuss codes and practice communicating a thousand words through the precise position of their left eye-brow. Participants are extremely talented and extremely smart (as long as their ability is reasonably and does not beggar suspension of disbelief).
2. The message is transmitted via speech, sight and maybe touch. Basically, participants and their informants see each other for five seconds and can hear whatever sound they make. In particular,

- No communication via objects. Books. Clothing. Speaking Parrots.
- No body modifications. No tattoos spelling out words. No special hair cuts. No intake of chemical substances. Informants look precisely as they did when the contestants last saw them. And the gods checked that they did not have "modifications" back then.
- Informants and participants are decided in advance. Participants cannot transfer information through their choice with whom to talk.
- No exchange of stuff. Hairs. DNA. Body fluids.

3. No recording. During these handful of seconds, participants only have their human brains to take note. They cannot film the scene to review later, write something down or use other technology to enhance their memory. They may strike a certain pose if that helps.

Now the question is: How much can participants convey? What would be their communication strategy? Any tricks on how to communicate faster? Sign-language? Cattle-Rapping? How do we abuse these short check-up as much as possible?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: How many words you can say is irrelevant as each word can be code for an entire essay of previously agreed data and concepts, so ***what do you mean*** by information? because the information imparted by individual words can vary depending on the meaning of those words and the shared understanding of the two participants of the implied concepts and information inherent in each word which can vary with the context of each words use .. under the correct conditions a single word can tell another person exactly what has happened and what they should do about it.

Comment: Vote to close as too story-based.

Comment: I must join @Daron and VTC:TSB. I'm also influenced by Nepe's answer, which is the only valid answer. The amount of information that can be conveyed is limited only by (a) the time available to prepare, (b) the amount of consultation available during the preparation time to analyze contingencies, (c) the memory capacity of the participants, and (d) *any context limiting the use of prepared information.* Between body language and voice, five seconds allows a number of informational triggers that is, for all practical purposes, infinite. (\*Continued\*)

Comment: ...  In short, as much information as you want - and that's based on [narrative necessity](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7281/40609).

Comment: @Daron, thank you for your criticism. Now that I received all these great answers, I will make the question more concise.
Unfortunately, I cannot follow the verdict of "too story-based". I ask about specific capabilities of characters to convey information in a given setting -- or what is likely to develop if characters use an ability "5 second talk" as best as possible.
Later, I give a description about the setting to address information like the ones you ask for. In particular, a-c) are covered, d) somewhat though I will work to highlight them.

Comment: To address your points:
a,b) "participants prepare since childhood and are the best with all the support one can think of"
c) They are exceptionally talented human persons. (I can highlight them being humans more.)
d) The person receiving in need of information is placed in a dungeon that can be anything. So they have all the information they can remember (and whatever is conveyed). There are limits. I would not expect one person to suddenly be able to explain the Hilbert operator after such a short discussion. Unless they learned it in preparation for their life-and-death battle (unlikely)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Language!

The straightforward use of a [Tamarian-like](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Darmok_(episode)) language that comes as a natural idea isn't really working as much as one might think.

I could associate each letter to a whole encyclopedia, but that does not mean that now the letter "W" carries all the information in Wikipedia (or "S" that of Stack Overflow); otherwise, there wouldn't be an about 1:10 ratio in how much we can compress ordinary text.

The same occurs with naval flag signaling. If you do have a flag (a symbol) that represents the concept you need, all well and good, wave that flag. If you don't? You need to use spelling flags, and "WHEAT" requires five of them. So, why not have *millions* of flags? We can do that: but perception limits prevent us from using infinitely *complex* flags (the same as speech prevents you from using infinitely many phonemes), so to have different flags, you need *larger* flags. The *bandwidth* of the flag is limited. And in the end (this is a [result](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(information_theory)) in Information Theory due to Claude Shannon), the space taken by fewer wider flags out of a large alphabet of flags will turn out to be *the same as the space taken by more flags out of a smaller alphabet*, provided that you want to convey all possible symbol combinations with equal probability. To have enough flags to have one that signifies WHEAT, your flags need to be five times as wide. The same if you use one small flag to say "use dictionary 17": you have several smaller dictionaries - and in dictionary 17, the WHEAT flag will be four units wide. Plus the one to signify dictionary 17, you're again at square one.

What one **can** do is to "map" the most likely concepts to the shortest, clearest, easiest possible syllables.

Languages already tend to do this: common concepts usually require short words, uncommon and rarely used concepts require longer words (this is also exploited in some novels, such as Delany's *Babel-17* - learning that a newly discovered race has seventeen short and easy words for different kinds of *war*, and/or they don't even have a word to say 'peace', is very bad news).

UTF8 charset also does this. Most common characters require *one* byte, then you have a special one-byte character that says *I am part of a two-byte sequence", another that says "I am part of a three-byte sequence". Since those longer characters are *rare*, you get to have and eat the most cake possible: *on average* you use little more than one byte, and your alphabet is now very wide.

So the first step is to develop a "battle language" where handier concepts are mapped to shorter syllables.

## Information

Language bandwidth allows maybe about one hundred syllables in the allotted five seconds (this from a quick googling of 'fastest rapper Guinness record'). At 6-7 bits per syllable (128 syllables, or maybe more than that but some combinations aren't pronounceable or otherwise viable), this gives us 700 bits of information using our battle language.

We have a problem just here, and let's assume it can be overcome with training: **remembering** those five seconds for the time it takes to "decode" the language. The receiver hasn't the advantage of having had the time to rehearse the speech and train delivering it. However, it's a language that both speak, so...

If the problem is solved or doesn't even exist, we start with a whopping 700 bits. This might well already be *more* than we need, because the transmitter will have also selected the information that's more relevant to their guy (a précis of how other players died is irrelevant - possibly not even who they were is. And yet technically that would be *information* too).

Can we get more? Yes. Static information can be conveyed with hair style and colour. The prohibition against *modifying your body* probably does not extend to shaving styles, hairstyles and so on. We wouldn't lose much if it did, because  I don't think we can squeeze more than maybe five or six bits out of this.

Dress? Unless there's a standardized garment to wear when communicating, that's information too. Color, shape, style all give information, and even limiting to top, shirt and lower body we easily get another twenty bits.

Also, this has the advantage of hitting *visual* memory, that runs *in parallel* with the Wernicke areas of the brain that are going to be over-stimulated by our compressed speech. Later recall would work.

Facial expression and body language also are something that would remain impressed and could be decoded later. A couple dozen expressions and gestures can be remembered and distinguished easily, and half a second is time enough for both generating and acquiring them. Of course the "transmitter" will have rehearsed their performance and will not get the sequences mixed up; if that holds, we have another forty bits to add to the total.

Also, the "receiver" could have transmitted information to the viewers during the god-game: writing on the ground with a stick, or using a variation of Fremen sand-walk to transmit Morse code when the "TV shows" broadcast them. Or if TV shows have also good audio and continuity (do the guys know when they're broadcast?), just "talking by themselves" could be enough.

Comment: thank you so much for your answer! It help a lot explore what such a system would lead to. I think your vocal bitrate might be a bit optimistic and that more information can be communicated with gestures (just showing fingers gives you at least 1 bit per finger) but the ballpark is interesting and the practical applications really help me think through this problem.
I really like you back-channeling idea. that has so much potential! Candidates write appealing diaries that TV stations would want to pick up just to hide questions in there for the "sender" to answer.

Answer (score 3):

## The content of a few dozen books.

The obvious way to communicate this is by exhaustively preparing a huge number of scenarios. They can design a compression algorithm that expands the data they can give so they can give them a fairly long set of numbers and letters which correlate to a few books. In the same way that many games use a seed to make a vast world, a seed will be chosen to convey more with less.

The algorithm will be designed to be fairly simple to expand and planned out by a super computer to give a message like this, of a few hundred characters.

This will give information like FY200, which will say that in fantasy book Y on page 200 the answer is given, which is that you're in a magical world with a steampunk tech level and magic based off dnd then IS133 which will say that there's a rare artifact at the coordinates given on this page which will give them an edge.

The goal is to rely on their memory, and extensive memorization of a huge variety of scenarios. That way, a small amount of information can point to a book.

Comment: To be fair, though, there's a difference between the size of the pool of information that can be drawn from and the actual amount of information that can be conveyed. The [average speaking speed is 130 words per minute](https://www.omnicalculator.com/everyday-life/words-per-minute) (we'll ignore being rushed right now) and that ignores any contextual changes like what "hello" means if my right hand is raised or not. That's about 11 words. There are about [one million words](https://englishlive.ef.com/blog/language-lab/many-words-english-language/) in the English language. (\*Continued\*)

Comment: ... Leaving us with about 999e27 word combinations... and let's assume each combination represents a single paragraph of [200 words](https://www.masterclass.com/articles/how-long-is-a-paragraph-explained) with an average word length of 4.7 characters... that means *the size of the information pool* is about 9.4e32 characters, which might be more than the total number of words in all books ever written in the English language. But let's compare that to what our intreped adverturers *just did.* (\*Continued\*)

Comment: ...They spoke 11 words, average length 4.7 characters. Max communication rate without contextual help: 52 characters. What's my point? The OP isn't clear about what he/she actually wants. Add tones, body language, etc., and the maximum communication rate is, at a complete guess, the equivalent of about 75 characters (it would be difficult to calculate how quickly a brain could distinguish the contextual difference in a word's meaning when that meaning isn't the natural definition of the word). (\*Continued\*)

Comment: ... So, one is limited in how much can be expressed, but not limited in the slightest by how much can be understood. I wonder what the OP really wants?

Comment: I am totally for candidates learning such reasonable compression schemes; this is what I am going for. Unfortunately, the candidate who needs the information is placed in magical world with a steampunk tech level. And it is not clear that this magical competition world contains book Y including page 200.
I like your idea of using computers, though, so candidates can learn algorithm A (which is reasonably easy to implement on whatever computer-thing there might be) just in case. In general though, I expect computer not to be available or candidates not learning to program them in 2 weeks.

Comment: You can work out algorithms with pen and paper, and presumably they would prepare ones simple enough to do that. 

And, they would memorize book Y, so they don't need it to be in the world. Memorizing books is quite possible for skilled adults.

Answer (score 2):

So, Wokopa has written a good answer - however - this is assuming standard languages. If we assume that a special, high-level language, where single words can have multiple complex meanings.

For example, the word 'Blegh' could have 10-20 different meanings depending on Context and...

- Pitch and Tonality of the voice.
- Facial Expression
- Hand Gesture
- Physical positioning

Now, to add some realism, we do a lot of this already in Language.

If someone just was to say 'run' in a normal context, you might not think much of it.

But if the same person Screams '**RUN!**' with a look of abject terror on their face, sprinting at full tilt and pointing in a direction it means:

"There's something potentially deadly and if you want to stay a live you should GTFO as fast as you can"

a custom designed language that was designed specifically to leverage these unique combinations could allow for a much higher throughput of information.

the bit rate of words would stay the same, but the meaning conveyed could be increased by several orders of magnitude.

Comment: *"The bit rate of words would stay the same, but the meaning conveyed could be increased by several orders of magnitude":* I am at a loss trying to understand the difference how one can transfer 2 bits of meaning with 1 bit of data. I suspect a most regrettable confusion between symbol rate and bit rate.

Comment: @AlexP - use the example of Run, 12 bits of data - that doesn't change, but given different inflections, facial expressions etc. Can convey many different meanings, some of which are significantly more complex than just 12 bits of data. With a fully developed system that combines all the elements of speech, hands, face, body etc. A few seconds of language (which is how we are measuring bit rate) can be enhanced to give additional meaning far exceeding that

Comment: And the inflecions and facial expression are what if not data? Are they some sort of "lesser" data and that's why you don't count them? Bit rate **is** the amount of data transferred per second. What I understand is that there are multiple data transmission channels, and the total bit rate is the sum of the bit rates of the parallel channels. Duh.

Comment: @AlexP - the 39 bits was referring to spoken and heard language - That's as fast as we can speak and hear. That doesn't change. Our understanding though of what is heard with a custom designed language that changes the meaning based on unique combinations of visual stimuli would enable for a much greater understanding. I've probably not articulated it very well - but the point is: a single short word having potentially 100s of different interpretations, based on visual stimuli. This would solve the problem posed by OP.

Answer (score 1):

## 39 bits per second

https://www.newscientist.com/article/2215202-all-languages-however-different-convey-information-at-the-same-rate/

> Human speech conveys information at 39 bits per second on average. That might not sound terribly impressive in an age where electronic devices exchange millions of bits of information per second, but it seems to be the optimum rate for people whatever language we speak.

> Francois Pellegrino’s team at the University of Lyon in France analysed 17 languages, from English to Japanese, that vary greatly in terms of the number of basic sounds, the number of syllables, the use of tones and so on. For instance, there are 7000 distinct syllables in English compared with just a few hundred in Japanese.

> The team worked out the information density of each language, in terms of bits of information per syllable. This varies from 5 bits per syllable for Basque to 8 bits per syllable for Vietnamese.

> Next, the team got 10 native speakers of each language – 170 people overall – to read 15 equivalent texts. What they found was that while the speech rate – in terms of syllables per second – varied from speaker to speaker, those speaking more information-dense languages speak more slowly on average.

> For instance, Basque was spoken at a rate of 8 syllables per second on average while Vietnamese was spoken at 5 syllables per second, making the rate at which information is conveyed similar for both.

Comment: A typical signature may take 3 seconds to write, and takes about 360 bits to encode. A large part of that is the kinematic model of your handwriting: the compression usually needs the time and pressure profile of your signature to capture this. If you sign your name on a whiteboard, you will use different muscles to write, but you will probably preserve the rhythm of writing, so the result will look much the same. So, this brackets Wokopa's answer: I get a figure of 60 bits per second, but a fraction of that is the handwriting style which does not transmit useful data.

Comment: @RichardKirk, there is also the problem that most people can only reliably do one signature (or at most a few). Just because there might be 2^360 signatures does not mean that one person can do them all. (Or another differentiate them all by eyesight).

Comment: Hi wokopa, thank you for your idea of addressing this problem. I think though it misses the question. As far as I understand the study, the measure humans talking normally, as opposed to humans trying to squeeze as much information as possible into five seconds. Still, it is super interesting to make-up limitations on what people can convey!

Comment: You could look in to [Ithkuil](https://conlang.stackexchange.com/questions/1255/are-there-any-successful-conlangs-using-information-density-as-a-design-goal) but I suspect the communication-rate limits on humans are there for a good reason.

Comment: Re signatures: you could presumably write something else. My point was I could get the same bit rate to within a factor of 2 from a completely different set of data, with a reasonable explanation that my higher figure contained only half useable data. A few people can type over 200 words per minute, which would be 13 5-bit characters a second, or 65 bits per second, but the actual entropy would probably be half that, as they could not type random characters nearly as fast.